# How to get tailMap for ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: dictionary, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap, java

I am using `TreeMap` to get `tailMap`, but its causing concurrency issues. So I decided to use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead. How do I get `tailMap` for `ConcurrentHashMap`?

There isn't any API like `map.tailMap(key)` for `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method is defined in the interface [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), so you need to use a map that implements that interface.  The likely concurrent candidate is [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).